# Workflow: Baking Before Texturing?

Tags: texturing, workflow, baking

I have a very basic question regarding character workflow.

First I sculpted a character, then I did the retopo. Now I'm wondering, should I bake (highres to lowres) before the texturing process or after. If it doesn't matter what's the best way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand where you're going with that question. Baking is a part of the texturing process. You bake the details of your hires model to a normal map. It also depends what type of model we're talking about and what materials you are going to use. At this point your question is too general to receive a detailed answer. Feel free to edit it and put more information in.

Comment: ok what I meant when saying texturing was painting in texture paint mode. But i guess my confusion was created by the lack of knowledge I have of baking.